# Add query parameter to existing parameters with route-helper

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.5

I use the route-helper (`{{ route('routename') }}`) in my Blade template files to filter and/or sort the results of the page.

What is the easiest way to attach a parameter to the previous ones?

As an example:

I visit the page `/category1` and see some products. Now I use the sorting which changes the URL to `/category1?sort_by=title&sort_order=asc`

If I use another filtering now, I would like the parameter to be appended to the current one. So to `/category1?sort_by=title&sort_order=asc&filter_by=year&year=2017` but the result is only `/category1?filter_by=year&year=2017` .

I create the Urls with the route-helper like:

```
route('category.show', [$category, 'sort_by' => 'title', 'sort_order' => 'asc'])
route('category.show', [$category, 'filter_by' => 'year', 'year' => $year])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use something like:

```
$new_parameters = ['filter_by' => 'year', 'year' => $year];

route('category.show', array_merge([$category], request()->all(), $new_parameters]);
```

to use all previous parameters and add new ones.

Obviously you might want to use only some of them, then instead of:

```
request()->all()
```

you can use:

```
request()->only('sort_by', 'sort_order', 'filter_by', 'year')
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I solved it now. Thanks for the tip. I was hoping laravel would have an even easier way to do this.
As long as no one can show me this one, that's the accepted answer. ;)